# Using custom fonts in Expo / Next.js: Module parse failed

Tags: react-native, next.js, expo, babeljs

**EDIT:** Instead of using Expo Fonts, I tried importing them from Google Fonts into the `<Head/>` under `_document.js` like so:

```js
<Head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@400;500;700&family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</Head>
```

**And it works wonderfully!**

---

**Original Question:**

I have tried following [Expo](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-nextjs/) and my current `next.config.js` looks like this:

```js
const { withExpo } = require("@expo/next-adapter");
const withFonts = require("next-fonts");

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = withExpo(
    {
        reactStrictMode: true,
        swcMinify: true,
        transpilePackages: [
            "react-native",
            "expo",
            "expo-linear-gradient",
            "expo-font",
            "react-native-svg",
            "lucide-react-native",
            "prop-types",
            // Add more React Native / Expo packages here...
        ],
        experimental: {
            forceSwcTransforms: true,
        },
    },
    withFonts({
        projectRoot: __dirname,
    })
);

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

However, I keep getting the following error in the debug window:

```
./public/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

**Current dependencies:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^47.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.0.1",
    "lucide-react-native": "^0.115.0",
    "next": "~13.1.1",
    "next-fonts": "^1.5.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7"
  },
```

I am enjoying using Next.js so far and this was my first bump on the road.

Thank you!

I've already searched and found some answers I could not replicate. The obvious answer would be my project do not know how to load .ttf and it should be fixed with Next-fonts. But I do not know how to set it up properly and tried various combinations from Stack and Expo with a few success, but the instant I changed font to e.g. Poppins or DM Sans, then the error instantly returned, even through the space-mono font worked a few times. I have no idea why it suddenly worked and suddenly didn't.